# How to use a query result in the expression of an embedded macro IF block

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, macros

I have an aggregated query which returns a count result. I want to use `IF` in the embedded macro to determine whether the count is greater than zero.

I tried:
[myquery]![countof ID]>0 but it doesn't execute as expected.

I don't know how to do this simple comparison in the `IF` statement in the macro.

I am unfamiliar with VBA and would prefer to use the macro builder. I have searched for a solution but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to pull information from a query in a macro, you can use a `DLOOKUP`.

This function requires two arguments: 1) Field Name and 2) Domain Name (can be a table or query). The third argument is optional and can be used to add criteria to the function. In your case, a third argument is not needed because we're extracting the only query result and do not need to further specify which row to return.

So your `IF` statement would be:

`IF DLOOKUP("[CountOf ID]", "MyQuery")>0`

See [MSDN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937) for more information on `DLOOKUPS`.